Generate interface without any fields
I am using Swagger codegen for generating some classes and I ran into some problems with duplicate fields.
Here is the config for those classes:
    GenericClass:
      type: object
      properties:
        objectType:
          type: string
          description: type of generic class implementation
      discriminator:
        propertyName: objectType
        mapping:
          TYPE_A: '#/components/schemas/ImplementationA'
          TYPE_B: '#/components/schemas/ImplementationB'

    ImplementationA:
      type: object
      description: Implementation A of GenericClass
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/GenericClass'
        - properties:
            ...some properties

    ImplementationB:
      type: object
      description: Implementation B of GenericClass
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/GenericClass'
        - properties:
            ...some properties

Basically whenever my API returns an object that uses those classes, the objectType field is duplicated. Since this objectType field has only 2 possible values (TYPE_A/TYPE_B), I came up with a workaround that would remove this field from the generated interface and then those fields would be hardcoded into the implementations.
How to generate an interface that doesn't have any field using Swagger codegen?
Is there another solution to this problem?
